# If the Higgs field was densified a little more, can the physical constants such as Planck Values be changed?

Tags: higgs, physical-constants

According to theory, the Higgs field is at everywhere in the space. So that, the mass is existing by interaction of energy (in some way) with this field.
And according to this the space vacuum has an energy density.

If energy density of this field was being a little different, how this will effect our universe?
Importance of this question (I think) caused from Special Relativity.
Because I ask this question, when an object speeds up, how will effect this added energy it or its environment (for example in a space ship)? Because the Energy can not be destroyed and then this energy (used for acceleration) should be dispersed on everything in the Ship. What about the Higgs Field?

Comment: The masses of fundamental particles (not protons and neutrons, but the quarks inside them) would increase in proportion to the "vacuum expectation value" of the field.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have a fundamental particle like a quark or an electron, then the mass of the fundamental particle is due to an interaction with the Higgs field called a Yukawa coupling. The mass of our particle is given by:

$$ m = y H_0 \tag{1} $$

where $y$ is the Yukawa coupling constant and $H_0$ is the vacuum expectation value (VEV) of the Higgs field. The Higgs field is unusual in have a VEV, $H_0$, that is non-zero and it is this non-zero VEV that causes the non-zero mass of the fundamental particles.

So if the VEV of the Higgs field were to change the particle mass would change according to equation (1).

If you're interested in learning more about this I strongly recommend [Matt Strassler's articles on the subject](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/how-the-higgs-field-works-with-math/). These will require some work, but no maths beyond school level is required.